# Different results with and without ga:pagePath dimension

Tags: google-analytics

I use the following query parameters in Google Analytics:

```
start-date=2017-10-01
end-date=2017-10-01
metrics=ga:users
```

When I filter by `ga:pagePath==/charity/` the result is `100`.

When I filter by `ga:pagePath=~/charity/` the result is `139`.

When I filter by `ga:pagePath=~/charity/;ga:pagePath!=/charity/` The result for some reason is `71`. How is it possible?

Moreover, if I add the ga:pagePath dimension when I filter by `ga:pagePath=~/charity/` I can see that the results add up to way more than 139. In fact, it shows that users for `/charity` is 100 and the rest of URLs add up to 137 (counted them manually). Could someone, please, help me to understand what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wager that at least part of the problem is that you query a user scope metric and filter by a hit based dimension.

A user can see multiple pages that contain "charity" in the url, so the total from all pages is more than total users, e.g, if one user has seen page /charity/a and page charity/b the rows would add to two users, but the absolute total is just the single person.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it! If I use ga:uniquePageviews everything sums up perfectly. Is there a way to know the scope of the metric? I don't see anything in the description of the ga:users that could give me a hint on where I was wrong.

Comment: Also, is there a way to count ga:users by ga:pagePath? I can do it on a client side with a simple loop, but maybe there is a way to do something like sum(ga:users) group by ga:pagePath? Probably not, though.

Comment: Unique Pageviews should for this use case be equivalent to "users" (since "unqiue" means "one per user").